# Convert arbitrary Golang interface to byte array

Tags: interface, go, arrays

I'm trying to write a hash that will accept all datatypes. Once in the function, I handle the data as a byte array. I'm having trouble figuring out how to cast an arbitrary `interface{}` to a byte array.

I tried using the binary package but it seemed to depend on the type of data passed in. One of the parameters of the `Write()` fn [(docs)](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write) required knowing the byte order of the parameter.

All datatype sizes are some multiple of a byte (even the bool), so this should be simple in theory.

Code in question below,

```
package bloom

import (
    "encoding/gob"
    "bytes"
)

// adapted from http://bretmulvey.com/hash/7.html
func ComputeHash(key interface{}) (uint, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
    err := enc.Encode(key)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    data := buf.Bytes()

    var a, b, c uint
    a, b = 0x9e3779b9, 0x9e3779b9
    c = 0;
    i := 0;

    for i = 0; i < len(data)-12; {
        a += uint(data[i+1] | data[i+2] << 8 | data[i+3] << 16 | data[i+4] << 24)
        i += 4
        b += uint(data[i+1] | data[i+2] << 8 | data[i+3] << 16 | data[i+4] << 24)
        i += 4
        c += uint(data[i+1] | data[i+2] << 8 | data[i+3] << 16 | data[i+4] << 24)

        a, b, c = mix(a, b, c);
    }

    c += uint(len(data))

    if i < len(data) {
        a += uint(data[i])
        i++
    }
    if i < len(data) {
        a += uint(data[i] << 8)
        i++
    }
    if i < len(data) {
        a += uint(data[i] << 16)
        i++
    }
    if i < len(data) {
        a += uint(data[i] << 24)
        i++
    }


    if i < len(data) {
        b += uint(data[i])
        i++
    }
    if i < len(data) {
        b += uint(data[i] << 8)
        i++
    }
    if i < len(data) {
        b += uint(data[i] << 16)
        i++
    }
    if i < len(data) {
        b += uint(data[i] << 24)
        i++
    }

    if i < len(data) {
        c += uint(data[i] << 8)
        i++
    }
    if i < len(data) {
        c += uint(data[i] << 16)
        i++
    }
    if i < len(data) {
        c += uint(data[i] << 24)
        i++
    }

    a, b, c = mix(a, b, c)
    return c, nil
}

func mix(a, b, c uint) (uint, uint, uint){
    a -= b; a -= c; a ^= (c>>13);
    b -= c; b -= a; b ^= (a<<8);
    c -= a; c -= b; c ^= (b>>13);
    a -= b; a -= c; a ^= (c>>12);
    b -= c; b -= a; b ^= (a<<16);
    c -= a; c -= b; c ^= (b>>5);
    a -= b; a -= c; a ^= (c>>3);
    b -= c; b -= a; b ^= (a<<10);
    c -= a; c -= b; c ^= (b>>15);

    return a, b, c
}
```

Comment: How about pkg "encoding/gob"? Can you use it?

Comment: @nvcnvn, seems to be working. I tried it earlier but now I realize there's a weakness in the hash on small values (0-62 are identical?). I changed the range I was working with any it now seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: fixed the errors in the hash fn, updated code found here: https://gist.github.com/natebrennand/10442587

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Other problems in my code led me away from the `gob` package earlier, turns out it was the proper way as @nvcnvn suggested. Relevant code on how to solve this issue below:

```
package bloom

import (
    "encoding/gob"
    "bytes"
)

func GetBytes(key interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
    err := enc.Encode(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}
```

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer as the answer to your question :)

Comment: Would be nice to have a example showing the usage of this method. For many beginners like me with Go, it would really help allot!

Comment: @RudiStrydom convert a map to bytes to save space? That is what I found this useful for.

Comment: At the time, I was trying to write a bloom filter that worked with arbitrary data structures. So by converting any struct/map/slice to`[]byte`, I could then process the byte slice into a hash.
https://gist.github.com/natebrennand/10442587

Answer (score 5):

Another way to convert `interface{}` to `[]bytes` is to use a fmt package.

```
/*
* Convert variable `key` from interface{} to []byte
*/

byteKey := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v", key.(interface{})))
```

fmt.Sprintf converts interface value to string.
[]byte converts string value to byte.

※ Note ※ This method does not work if interface{} value is a pointer. Please find @PassKit's comment below.

Comment: This could have unexpected results if the interface is a pointer you will get a memory address. https://play.golang.org/p/EgjvrqOyxEi

Comment: it's worth to mention in your answer what @PassKit said in his comment