# go and parsing token with jwt-go

Tags: go, jwt, jwt-go

Could anyone tell me why the following (from https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go) example doesn't work?

```
token, err := jwt.Parse(myToken, func(token *jwt.Token) ([]byte, error) {
    return myLookupKey(token.Header["kid"])
})

if err == nil && token.Valid {
    deliverGoodness("!")
} else {
    deliverUtterRejection(":(")
}
```

I get an error saying `cannot use func literal (type func(*jwt.Token) ([]byte, error)) as type jwt.Keyfunc in argument to jwt.Parse`

I've tried to use the code from couple of different jwt-go examples but always ended up with this same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function [`Parse`](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/blob/ed420779288d0fec5f095f6da7923d09e3108c05/jwt.go#L93) expects

```
type Keyfunc func(*Token) (interface{}, error)
```

You need to return `interface{}`, not `byte[]` in your function literal.
(maybe using a [`byte.Buffer`](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) to wrap the `byte[]`, that you can then read as in "[Convert arbitrary Golang interface to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23004209/6309)")

[Gert Cuykens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172754/gert-cuykens) points out in the comments to [issue 36](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/issues/36): [commit e1571c8](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/commit/e1571c8f043ba6c328509ad1bd36bbd0ece97d9c) should have updated the example.
[Other examples like this gist](https://gist.github.com/cryptix/45c33ecf0ae54828e63b#file-asymmetric-go-L152) also need to be updated.

Comment: Well, I'll be... That's it, now everything seems to work as expected. The funniest thing is that in the Github of jwt-go they use []byte in the example. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the change to interface{} happened fairly recently: https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/commit/23cb3af02c1259a5058fcb1402424442ec9b03ab  Might want to ping the author to fix their documentation.

Comment: @GertCuykens good bug report. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in another answer, the most recent version of is `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go` is `v3.2.0+incompatible`.
The docs are now outdated as the package's [`jwt.Keyfunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#Keyfunc)
function now has this signature:

```golang
type Keyfunc func (*Token) (interface{}, error)
```

When parsing JWTs, this `jwt` package also authenticates them. Two things are required to authenticate JWTs.

1. The JWT itself.
2. The cryptographic key that was used to sign the JWT. Typically, this is a public key.

This is where the [`jwt.Keyfunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#Keyfunc) fits in. The return value
of `interface{}` is later type asserted to a cryptographic key. For many use cases, this will be an RSA or ECDSA based
algorithm. This means the return type is typically [`*ecdsa.PublicKey`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/#PublicKey)
or [`*rsa.PublicKey`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#PublicKey). (HMAC keys can also be used, but I won't cover that
use case.)

If your public keys are in PEM format, you might be interested in using the functions built into the `jwt`
package: [`ParseECPublicKeyFromPEM`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go@v3.2.0+incompatible#ParseECPublicKeyFromPEM)
and [`ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go@v3.2.0+incompatible#ParseECPublicKeyFromPEM)
.

## Creating a public key data structure

If your public keys are in another format, you may need to build
the [`*ecdsa.PublicKey`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/#PublicKey)
and [`*rsa.PublicKey`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#PublicKey) Go structs by populating their exported fields.

### ECDSA

Here's the data structure to fill:

```golang
// PublicKey represents an ECDSA public key.
type PublicKey struct {
    elliptic.Curve
    X, Y *big.Int
}
```

The embedded `elliptic.Curve` is created by using the `crypto/elliptic` function associated with its length:

```golang
// Create the ECDSA public key.
publicKey = &ecdsa.PublicKey{}

// Set the curve type.
var curve elliptic.Curve
switch myCurve {
    case p256:
        curve = elliptic.P256()
    case p384:
        curve = elliptic.P384()
    case p521:
        curve = elliptic.P521()
}
publicKey.Curve = curve
```

For both `X` and `Y`, these are `*big.Int`s. If you have the bytes for these integers, creating a new `*big.Int` and
using the [`SetBytes`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.SetBytes) method.

```golang
publicKey.X = big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(xCoordinate)
publicKey.Y = big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(yCoordinate)
```

### RSA

Here's the data structure to fill:

```golang
// A PublicKey represents the public part of an RSA key.
type PublicKey struct {
    N *big.Int // modulus
    E int      // public exponent
}
```

The modulus, `N` is a `*big.Int`. If you have the bytes for this integer, create a new `*big.Int` and using the
[`SetBytes`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.SetBytes) method.

```golang
publicKey.N = big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(modulus)
```

The exponent is a regular integer. So that should be strait forward, but if you have the bytes for this integer instead
you can create an integer like this:

```golang
publicKey.E = int(big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(exponent).Uint64())
```

## Create a [`jwt.Keyfunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go@v3.2.0+incompatible#Keyfunc)

Now that the public keys are in the right data strucuture, it's time to create
a [`jwt.Keyfunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go@v3.2.0+incompatible#Keyfunc). As mentioned before, the
input for this function will be
a [`*jwt.Token`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go@v3.2.0+incompatible#Token) and the output will be either
an [`*ecdsa.PublicKey`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/#PublicKey) or a
[`*rsa.PublicKey`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#PublicKey), but typed as an empty interface: `interface{}`, or
an `error`.

The [`*jwt.Token`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go@v3.2.0+incompatible#Token) contains the JWT itself,
but the best way to identify which public key it's associated with is the `kid`. The `kid` is a string value contained
in the JWT header. Read about the
[`kid` parameter in the RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517#section-4.5). It can be read from the JWT
like this:

```golang
// ErrKID indicates that the JWT had an invalid kid.
ErrKID := errors.New("the JWT has an invalid kid")

// Get the kid from the token header.
kidInter, ok := token.Header["kid"]
if !ok {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("%w: could not find kid in JWT header", ErrKID)
}
kid, ok := kidInter.(string)
if !ok {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("%w: could not convert kid in JWT header to string", ErrKID)
}
```

At this point, the input is a `kid` and the output is the public key. The simplest implementation of a
[`jwt.Keyfunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go@v3.2.0+incompatible#Keyfunc) at this point is a function
that reads from a `map[string]interface{}` where the key `string` is a `kid` and value `interface{}` is its public key.

Here's an example:

```golang
// ErrKID indicates that the JWT had an invalid kid.
ErrKID := errors.New("the JWT has an invalid kid") // TODO This should be exported in the global scope.

// Create the map of KID to public keys.
keyMap := map[string]interface{}{"zXew0UJ1h6Q4CCcd_9wxMzvcp5cEBifH0KWrCz2Kyxc": publicKey}

// Create a mutex for the map of KID to public keys.
var mux sync.Mutex

// Create the jwt.Keyfunc
var keyFunc jwt.Keyfunc = func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {

    // Get the kid from the token header.
    kidInter, ok := token.Header["kid"]
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%w: could not find kid in JWT header", ErrKID)
    }
    kid, ok := kidInter.(string)
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%w: could not convert kid in JWT header to string", ErrKID)
    }

    // Get the appropriate public key from the map of KID to public keys.
    mux.Lock()
    publicKey, ok := keyMap[kid]
    mux.Unlock()
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%w: could not find a matching KID in the map of keys", ErrKID)
    }

    return publicKey, nil
}
```

You can now use the created `keyFunc` function-as-a-variable when parsing JWTs.

```golang
// Parse the JWT.
token, err := jwt.Parse(myToken, keyFunc)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to parse JWT.\nError: %s\n", err.Error())
}

// Confirm the JWT is valid.
if !token.Valid {
    log.Fatalln("JWT failed validation.")
}

// TODO Proceed with authentic JWT.
```

## Other JWT public key formats

JWTs' public keys can also be described by [RFC 7517](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517). This RFC describes
a JSON Web Key (JWK) and JSON Web Key Set (JWKs). Some identity providers, like [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/)
or [Amazon Cognito (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) provide these via HTTPS endpoints.

Here's an example JWKs:

```json
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kid": "zXew0UJ1h6Q4CCcd_9wxMzvcp5cEBifH0KWrCz2Kyxc",
      "kty": "RSA",
      "alg": "PS256",
      "use": "sig",
      "n": "wqS81x6fItPUdh1OWCT8p3AuLYgFlpmg61WXp6sp1pVijoyF29GOSaD9xE-vLtegX-5h0BnP7va0bwsOAPdh6SdeVslEifNGHCtID0xNFqHNWcXSt4eLfQKAPFUq0TsEO-8P1QHRq6yeG8JAFaxakkaagLFuV8Vd_21PGJFWhvJodJLhX_-Ym9L8XUpIPps_mQriMUOWDe-5DWjHnDtfV7mgaOxbBvVo3wj8V2Lmo5Li4HabT4MEzeJ6e9IdFo2kj_44Yy9osX-PMPtu8BQz_onPgf0wjrVWt349Rj6OkS8RxlNGYeuIxYZr0TOhP5F-yEPhSXDsKdVTwPf7zAAaKQ",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "x5c": [
        "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"
      ],
      "x5t": "IYIeevIT57t8ppUejM42Bqx6f3I",
      "x5t#S256": "TuOrBy2NcTlFSWuZ8Kh8W8AjQagb4fnfP1SlKMO8-So"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the above example, a [`*rsa.PublicKey`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#PublicKey) can be created from just the
`n` and `e` JSON attributes. It's `kid` attribute can be used to create an entry in the `keyMap` described in an earlier
section.

I've actually run into this use case before and created a Go package just for consuming JWKs and creating
[`jwt.Keyfunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go@v3.2.0+incompatible#Keyfunc). If this fits your use case,
check out the repository here: [`github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc`](https://github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc).